# pgfplots: place second y-axis at fixed x-position

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

I have a second y-axis, that is a '(purple) q-axis'. 
What do I have to set to place the second y-axis through (1,0) at the original coordinate system (black).

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
x=3cm, % needed
%y=1cm, 
axis lines=middle, 
xlabel= $\overline{x}$,
ylabel= $\overline{y}$,
axis line style={-latex},
]
\addplot[domain=0.05:2.5, black]{-(1-x)^2/x};
\addplot[domain=-2.5:-0.05, black]{-(1-x)^2/x};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[purple, 
hide x axis, 
axis lines*=middle, 
ylabel= $q$,
y label style={rotate=-90, 
at={(ticklabel* cs:0.95)}, anchor=west,   },
% Problem ===================
shift={(3cm,0)}, % ???
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can add

```
\coordinate (axis2origin) at (1,0);
```

to the first `axis` environment, and

```
anchor=origin,
shift={(axis2origin)},
```

to the options of the second. As you might expect, the origin of the second axis will be placed in (1,0) of the first.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
x=3cm, % needed
%y=1cm, 
axis lines=middle, 
xlabel= $\overline{x}$,
ylabel= $\overline{y}$,
axis line style={-latex},
]
\addplot[domain=0.05:2.5, black]{-(1-x)^2/x};
\addplot[domain=-2.5:-0.05, black]{-(1-x)^2/x};

\coordinate (axis2origin) at (1,0);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[purple, 
hide x axis, 
axis lines*=middle, 
ylabel= $q$,
y label style={rotate=-90, 
at={(ticklabel* cs:0.95)}, anchor=west,   },
% Problem ===================
anchor=origin,
shift={(axis2origin)},
 % ???
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```